# Drawing a number of balls from $n$ numbered balls $k+1$ times with replacement

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients

Consider:

$E_j$: the maximum of the values obtained on $k + 1$ draws is $j$, $j = 1,\ldots,n$,

$F_j$: all the draws are done on $\{1,\ldots,j\}$, $j = 1,\ldots,n$,

$F_0 = \emptyset$.

1. Calculate $|S|$.
   Here, I think that if we execute the action steps by steps, we'll have n possibilities each time so n^(k+1) possibilities after (k+1) times drawing balls. Then
   $$
   |S| = n^{k+1}
   $$
   The thing is the number of balls drawn is not defined, so I think to another situation.
   I'll divide the experience in many cases where: draw $1$ ball, $2$ balls then draw $n$ balls. So far, we receive $|S| = 1^{k+1} + 2^{k+1}+\ldots+n^{k+1}$.
   But I am not sure about my procedure above.
2. Write $S$ as a set operation on $E_1,\ldots, E_n$.
   Like for the first question, I'll solve the problem in many cases where $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.
   With $j=1$, we have $|E_1| = k+1$ because when $1$ is the maximum value observed, we draw only $1$ ball. After $k+1$ times, there are $k+1$ possibilities where $E_1$ can be performed. With the same reason, 
   $$
   |E_n| = (k+1) 2^{n-1}.
   $$
   Then 
   $$
   |E_j| = (k+1) (1+4+8+...+2^{n-1}).
   $$
3. Write $E_j$ as a set operation on $F_{j-1}; F_j$, $j = 1,\ldots,n$.
4. Calculate $|F_j|$, $j = 0,\ldots,n$.
5. Calculate $|E_j|$, $j = 1,\ldots,n$.
6. Calculate $|S|$, through the computation of $|E_j|$, $j = 1,\ldots,n$ and using the binomial of Newton.

Overall, I don't really understand what the event $F_j$ is. And please correct me and give me some suggestions, please. Ty

Comment: Here, I thought for the 1st question, we have n^ (k+1) possibilities, but I am not sure if the order is counted or not.

Comment: Why $k+1$ rather than another variable $k^\prime (= k+1)$?  It seems you could have used $k + 392$ just as well!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I'm new on MSE so I am not really familiar with the platform, thanks so much for your comments :) I added my thoughts and my solutions for the problem. Please give a look :)